# RxJS several input streams. Proper way to deal with them?

Tags: rxjs

I have five inputs on my app and I want to calculate the sum of each of them in a final number.

So far I did this:

```
const input1 = document.querySelector("#text1");
const input2 = document.querySelector("#text2");
const input3 = document.querySelector("#text3");
const input4 = document.querySelector("#text4");
const input5 = document.querySelector("#text5");

function setObservable(selector) {
    return Rx.Observable
        .fromEvent(selector, "input")
        .map(event => parseInt(event.target.value))
        .startWith(0)
}

const input$ = setObservable(input1)
const input2$ = setObservable(input2)
const input3$ = setObservable(input3)
const input4$ = setObservable(input4)
const input5$ = setObservable(input5)


const source = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(input$, input2$, input3$, input4$, input5$)

source.subscribe(value => {
    const totalHTML = document.querySelector(".total");
    const total = value.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0);

    totalHTML.textContent = total;
});
```

Which is working fine... but is there any more elegant way to get the values of each input without specifying all of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure! Let's store all your selectors in an array:

```
const selectors = ['#text1', '#text2', '#text3', '#text4', '#text5'];
```

And let's map over these to get the actual elements:

```
const elements = selectors.map(s => document.querySelector(s));
```

And now let's map over these elements and get an array of Observables:

```
const clickStreams = elements.map(setObservable);
```

And finally we can combine latest (like you did before):

```
const click$ = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(clickStreams);
```